# How to rewrite the chained conditional or logic with includes method of JS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to avoid multiple logical OR conditional checks with `||` using includes. Could anyone please help how to achieve that using array's include method?

```js
const cars = [{
  name: 'BMW',
  year: '2020'
}, {
  name: 'Audi',
  year: '2019'
}, {
  name: 'Benz',
  year: '2018'
}]

const result = cars.includes(['BMW', 'Audi'])

console.log(result);
```

Comment: So you expect `result` to be `true` if there is at least one array element with the name "BMW" or "Audi"? `Array#includes` can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for this. In your case even twice:

```js
const cars = [{
  name: 'BMW',
  year: '2020'
}, {
  name: 'Audi',
  year: '2019'
}, {
  name: 'Benz',
  year: '2018'
}]


const result = ['BMW', 'Audi'].some((searchedName) => cars.some((car) => car.name === searchedName));

console.log(result);
```

This is not a solution with a focus on performance but rather a focus on avoiding `||`.

Comment: Great! How do i get the objects in from the array which are found. That is, `[{
  name: 'BMW',
  year: '2020'
}, {
  name: 'Audi',
  year: '2019'
}]`

Comment: Could you please let me know how do i return the values instead of boolean result? @Benjamin

Comment: Please try yourself. It's really not that hard. Little hint: you need to shuffle the code a but and use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter instead of `some` in one place.

Comment: BTW: This question was closed referencing an entry that should apply to your case.